# Indexing document to solrcloud cluster present inside amazon VPC

Tags: indexing, solr, solrcloud, amazon-vpc

I am moving my solr cloud machines to amazon VPC and the machine from which I am going to index the data to the solr machines is outside VPC. As far as I know the bin/post utility in solr doesn't provide a way of proxying the request to the solr machines. 
So, how do I index my files to solr machines from a machine that is outside the VPC network.